# Names with numbers after the name (regular expressions)

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a regular expression which I do not understand. The expression is:

```
/^[A-Za-z\s\.\(\)]{3,}$/
```

The problem I am having is that I would have a name, e.g The Test 11 and that is fine, but this regular expression is returning false on anything with a number after it. Can anyone help me out on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well is returning false because you didn't include numbers on your pattern, this should work:

```
/^[A-Za-z\s.\(\)0-9]{3,}$/
```

P.S. You need to escape `(` and `)` if you want those characters to be included in your pattern.